# Unable to define max length for ESAPI SafeString Type

Tags: java, validation, input, owasp, esapi

I'm trying to use ESAPI in my existing project. 
I'm getting an error while trying to use `ESAPI.validator().getValidInput()` method for SafeString type.

The following is an auto defined Regex, contained in the `validation.properties` file:

```
Validator.SafeString=^[.\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}]{0,1024}$
```

I assumed that the max length is 1024.

This is my code:

```
ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("Validationofinput",_appendToSelect,"SafeString",1024, true)
```

However, I received the following error:

> WARN  IntrusionDetector  - [SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown ->
>   /ExampleApplication/IntrusionDetector]  Invalid input:
>   context=Validationofinput,
>   type(SafeString)=^[.\p{Alnum}\p{Space}]{0,1024}$, input=and
>   ProductCategory like '%test_%'
>   org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException: Validationofinput: Invalid
>   input. Please conform to regex ^[.\p{Alnum}\p{Space}]{0,1024}$ with a
>   maximum length of 1024    at
>   org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.checkWhitelist(StringValidationRule.java:144)
>     at
>   org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.checkWhitelist(StringValidationRule.java:160)
>     at
>   org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.getValid(StringValidationRule.java:284)
>     at
>   org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator.getValidInput(DefaultValidator.java:214)
>     at
>   org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator.getValidInput(DefaultValidator.java:185)

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: We can, but not without the input.

Comment: @avgvstvs, what do u mean? i have input there which is  input=and ProductCategory like '%test_%'

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

This is failing because your input doesn't match the regular expression, not because of a length violation.

The Posix standard specifies that `\p{Alnum}` corresponds to the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and `\p{Space}` corresponds to `\s`.  In your case, your input will fail because of the characters: `'` and `%` and `_`

`^[.\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}]{0,1024}$`:

`^` == At the beginning of the line

`[` == Start a character class, match any of the following characters in any order

`.` == Match an ASCII period

`\\p{Alnum}` == Match any ASCII alphabet character or number, upper or lower case.

`\\p{Space}` == Match any ASCII whitespace

`]` == End character class

`{0,1024}` == Match any number of characters from 0 to 1024

`$` == All the way until the end of the line.